# Mediation Model for two predicting variables with opposing effects on the moderator

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, mediation

I have a research question where I argue that X1 and X2 affect M which ultimately affects Y.

My problem is I expect the effect of X1 on M to be positive and X2 on M to be negative.

In this case, how do I interpret the b path? My problem is, X1 and X2 are mutually exclusive and do not appear on the same individual. I am inclined towards using SEM on R at the moment but I am seeking ideas. Any suggestion is extremely appreciated.